# Android adding Google Play Services SDK

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have am building a game using LibGDX framwork, I am trying to add AdMod to my game. I have followed the instructions on this link.

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Even though it is not giving me any errors, when I try to import any google play services class eg `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` it does not recognise it.

Also one thing that i noticed, When I added google-play-services_lib it showed a green tick on it in my project property as shown below.

[image]

But on closing the property window and checking it again the green tick changed into red cross.

[image]

Repeating the task gave same results

Comment: Are you sure that you have the latest `google-play-services-lib`?

Comment: yes google play services lib revision is 16 and the version number in their xml is 4323000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported the ...-lib as a project? Try again and while doing this try clicking the option that adds a copy of the files to your workspace, and then accesses them from there. Add as library again at this point.

Comment: you are awesome man. I really would like to know why importing the project into the workspace did the trick?